# how to apply string style to an element in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamic style model as a string, which I want to apply to a html element.
Unfortunately ng-style works with objects.

How can I make this work with a simple string?

item.trStyle is something like `"background-color:#B5EFF2;padding:10px;text-align:center;"`

```
<td style="{{item.trStyle}}">

</td>
```

Comment: Use ng-style, not style https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: I tried with ng-style and not working. Expecting an object.

Comment: Right..so put your css into an object {'background-color': '#B5EFF2','padding':'10px','text-align':'center'}

Comment: so does this style change depending on a circumstance or is this just a static style?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use ng-class with several different classes that builds the style you want. For example..

```
<td ng-class="{blueBG: shouldBeBlue, tenPadding: shouldBePadding, centerText: shouldCenterText}">
```

css...

```
.blueBG{background-color:#B5EFF2;}
.tenPadding{padding:10px;}
.centerText{text-align:center;}
```

angular model

```
{
$scope.shouldBeBlue = true;
$scope.shouldBePadding = true;
$scope.shouldCenterText = true;
}
```

Comment: impossible to do that. what if there are 100 x css styles and values?